# sqlite order by random groups

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table of songs with track and album columns and I want to get them in a random album order. i.e. such that in each album the songs will be sorted but the albums will be in random order.

For example, if the table is:

```
-----------------
| track | album |
-----------------
| 1     | a     |
| 2     | a     |
| 3     | a     |
| 1     | b     |
| 2     | b     |
| 1     | c     |
| 2     | c     |
-----------------
```

than a possible output will be

```
-----------------
| track | album |
-----------------
| 1     | b     |
| 2     | b     |
| 1     | c     |
| 2     | c     |
| 1     | a     |
| 2     | a     |
| 3     | a     |
-----------------
```

Can it be done with a single sqlite query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add an ordering to MrSimpleMind's answer in order to achieve the desired order:

```
WITH albums AS (SELECT DISTINCT album FROM songs ORDER BY RANDOM()) 
SELECT songs.* FROM albums
LEFT JOIN songs
ON songs.album = albums.album
ORDER BY albums.rowid, songs.track
```

Answer (score 3):

First you need to order the albums randomly, and then select the tracks.

```
with tt as (
  select distinct album from t order by random()
)
select t.track, tt.album 
from tt left join t on t.album = tt.album
order by tt.rowid, t.track
;
```

See [Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/df4a5/1)

Comment: it doesn't sort the tracks on each album

Comment: I added the order as it was a simple order by the albums rowid and the track. good luck. I verified with new sqlfiddle , that was the delay http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/0994c/1